# for loop is not executed /getting error like loop is not working

Tags: php, mysql

In my example below the for loop is not executed and / or my data is not being inserted into the database. What can I change?

```
   <?php
    include('connection.php');
    {
   if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
     {
   date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
   $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());

   for ($i=1; $i<=$_POST["NUM_STUDENTS"]; $i++) {

      $STD = "STUDENT_ID".$i;
      $DS = "DISCOUNT".$i;
      $LV = "LEAVE".$i;
      $FN = "FINE".$i;

 $sql  = "INSERT INTO ATTENDANCE";
 $sql .= "(SESSION_ID,ORG_ID,GRADE_ID,MONTH,STUDENT_ID,DISCOUNT,LEAVE,FINE,SOURCE,CREATEDTTM,UPDDTTM,DELETE_FLAG)";

    $sql .= "VALUES "; 
   $sql .=  "('".$_POST["SESSION_ID"]."','".$_POST["ORG_ID"]."','".$_POST["GRADE_ID"]."','".$_POST["MONTH"]."','".$_POST[$STD]."','".$_POST[$DS]."','".$_POST[$LV]."','".$_POST[$FN]."' ";

   $sql .= ",'".$_SESSION['login_name']."','".$date."','".$date."','N')";
  $objQuery_2 = mysql_query($sql);
  if($objQuery_2) 
   {                                                      
   echo"<script>alert('Attendance Fine Added Successfully')</script>"; 
  header("refresh:0;url=attendance_srch.php");
    exit();
      }
   else
  {
 echo"<script>alert('Please Check Data')</script>";
   header("refresh:0;url=attendance_srch.php");
    exit();
   }
  }
 }
  mysql_close($bd);
 ob_flush();
 }
   ?>
```

Comment: Never, never use GET data directly in a query. You ask for sql injection !

Answer (score 0):

You have left a lot space here between **`?`** and **`>`** must be **`?>`**  . *[This is one of the errors]*

```
<?=$objResult["OPERATOR_ID"];?   >">
                              ^^^
```

must be

```
<?=$objResult["OPERATOR_ID"];?>">
```

Comment: but i get same error and row is alredy fetch with open the  search page

Answer (score 0):

Array keys are case sensitive. If the actual names of the input is `OPERATOR_ID`, then you can't access it with `$_GET['operator_id']`, you have to use `$_GET['OPERATOR_ID']`.

Another problem is that you have an extra set of braces. So you're doing all the database code even if the `if (isset($_GET['OPERATOR_ID'])` is false.

Comment: but i get same error and row is alredy fetch with open the search page